# Как по клику перезагрузить страницу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть страница на которой имеется блок сразными чекбоксами
и у меня возникает **иногда** необходимость сбросить чекбоксы, и я решил чтобы не искать все включенные чекбоксы и не снимать галки можно просто перезагрузить страницу.

Я подумал что мне нужна кнопка по клику на которую страница перезагружалась
Но не пойму как прописать код, единственное что смог это добавить кнопку

```
document.querySelectorAll('.woosb-products').forEach(n => {
  n.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<button id="my_s" >click me</button>');
});
```

а как вот сделать чтоб страница перезагружалась ПРИ КЛИКЕ, ..... неразберусь, непойму, гуглиние чето мне не помогло, найденые примеры не работают..

Как по клику перезагрузить  страницу полностью разобрался

```
document.querySelectorAll('.woosb-products').forEach(n => {
  n.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<button id="something" >Перезагрузить</button>');
});
$('#something').click(function() { location.reload();
});
```

... а  как перезагрузить только блок class="myDiv" без полной перезагрузки страницы -если это возможно...?

ПО КЛИКУ ...

Comment: [location.reload(true)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#example_2_force_reloading_the_current_page_from_the_server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> И я решил чтобы не искать все включенные чекбоксы и не снимать галки можно просто перезагрузить страницу.

Зря,

```js
let cb = document.querySelectorAll('#your-box [type="checkbox"]');

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  cb.forEach(e => e.checked = false);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">reset</button>

<div id="your-box">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span><input type="checkbox" checked></span>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span><input type="checkbox"></span>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span><input type="checkbox"></span>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span><input type="checkbox" checked></span>
</div>
```

Чудо-метода перезагрузки конкретного блока не существует (кажется о_О).

Также, можно заключить всё в тег `<form>` и воспользоваться его встроенным методом [form.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset). Только, он приводит форму в исходное состояние, а не отключает чекбоксы. Т.е. если какие-то были включены по умолчанию, они останутся включенными.

Answer (score 2):

Все куда проще, даже без js можна сделать:

```html
<form id="form" action="">
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox6" type="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox7" type="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox8" type="checkbox">

    <input id="reset__button" type="reset">
</form>
```